# C# Update CRC value in XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML that I need to update the CRC value for each group.  I have the routine written to calculate the value but not sure what the best way is to read the XML, parse each section and then update the CRC value.

This is a sample of the XML file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This XML file was generated by Protocol Editor -->
<!-- The Group Names are ignored by the Assay Algorithms, but could have a useful meaning for users. -->
<protocols xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="GENII_protocols.UTF08.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<assay_protocol   carttype="1"  name="Calibration"  CRC32="F3C2D665">
    <group name="ChannelsMap" channel="CONSTANTS">
        <parameter name="outerProximal" value="0"/>
        <parameter name="innerProximal" value="1"/>
        <parameter name="innerDistal" value="2"/>
        <parameter name="outerDistal" value="3"/>
    </group>
    <group name="AssayIdentity" channel="CONSTANTS">
        <parameter name="AssayName" value="Calibration"/>
        <parameter name="AssayType" value="1"/>
    </group>
    <group name="AssaySubSystem" channel="ASSAY">
        <parameter name="FillTimeBuffer" value="8"/>
        <parameter name="AssayTime" value="120"/>
        <parameter name="SampleRate" value="2"/>
    </group>
    <group name="ProfileForGENII" channel="ASSAY">
        <parameter name="MixingWaveAmpCmnd" value="@ao7600FF#"/>
        <parameter name="MixingWaveFormCmnd" value="@AIFF#"/>
        <parameter name="MixingProfileCmnd" value="@AC 5 5 1000 10 64 64 1000 9 31 35 1000 119 FF#"/>
        <parameter name="SamplingProfileCmnd" value="@AE000112233FF#"/>
    </group>
</assay_protocol>
<assay_protocol   carttype="1"  name="Calibration2"  CRC32="F3C2D665">
    <group name="ChannelsMap" channel="CONSTANTS">
        <parameter name="outerProximal" value="0"/>
        <parameter name="innerProximal" value="1"/>
        <parameter name="innerDistal" value="2"/>
        <parameter name="outerDistal" value="3"/>
    </group>
    <group name="AssayIdentity" channel="CONSTANTS">
        <parameter name="AssayName" value="Calibration"/>
        <parameter name="AssayType" value="1"/>
    </group>
    <group name="AssaySubSystem" channel="ASSAY">
        <parameter name="FillTimeBuffer" value="8"/>
        <parameter name="AssayTime" value="120"/>
        <parameter name="SampleRate" value="2"/>
    </group>
    <group name="ProfileForGENII" channel="ASSAY">
        <parameter name="MixingWaveAmpCmnd" value="@ao7600FF#"/>
        <parameter name="MixingWaveFormCmnd" value="@AIFF#"/>
        <parameter name="MixingProfileCmnd" value="@AC 5 5 1000 10 64 64 1000 9 31 35 1000 119 FF#"/>
        <parameter name="SamplingProfileCmnd" value="@AE000112233FF#"/>
    </group>
</assay_protocol>
</protocols>
```

The CRC is calculated from each line in the associated protocol and then the result needs to be placed in the CRC32 value.

Comment: I hope only the content of elements, not the serialized form. Otherwise you got to take Canonicalization into account.

Comment: Need the full line not just the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do the job

```
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("example.xml");
        var protocols = from protocol in xDoc.Descendants("assay_protocol")
                select protocol;
        protocols.ToList().ForEach((entry) => { var r = entry.CreateReader();
                                                r.MoveToContent();
                                                entry.SetAttributeValue("CRC32", CRC32Function(r.ReadInnerXml()));
        });
```

But be very wary when calculating CRC's for serialized XML.

```
 <SomElement a="Hello" b="world" />
```

is the same xml as

```
 <SomeElement b="World" a="Hello" />
```

but will yield a different CRC value of course.

You need to Canonicalize your XML before serialization to guarantee correct functionality.

Hope this helps,